# Is there a fast way to get a docview link to a specific page in a PDF document?

Tags: docview, org-link

When I press "w" in eww-mode i get the link to the opened Homepage. Now I can yank this link very fast in an Org Mode file.

How can I get such a link to a specific page in an open PDF document in the docview-mode?

I want to find a fast way to create a docview-link to a specific page in Org Mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `org-docview` which allows you to create usual org-links to documents open in docview-mode. Using `C-c l` you can store a link and using `C-c C-l` you can insert it.

I would actually suggest using `pdf-tools` with `org-pdfview`. Both are on melpa and on github.

Comment: I missed `(global-set-key "\C-cl" 'org-store-link)` in my init file. Thanks.